# How to hide and copy a checkbox using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the base column with the checkbox, (the D column in my code), and i want to copy that column with the checbox to the other columns, but the column D must be hide(all the data including the checkbox).

the problem here is:

1. i don't know how to hide the checbox, when i hide the column the checbox still visible.
2. when i coppy the column the checbox in the colum does not be copied

This is the fuction that i actually used.

```
    Private Sub cmdAddNewXref_Click()
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy

    i = 3
    Cells(2, i).Select
    Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop While Cells(2, i) <> ""
    Cells(2, i).Select

    'MsgBox ActiveCell.Column

    Columns(i - 1).Select
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Columns(i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A1").Select
    End Sub
```

but most importantly what i want to do, is possible?

EDIT 1: actually thanks to Scott Holtzman i can hide the checkbox with the columns.

Comment: No vba required to solve this issue. Right-click on check-box and select `Format Control` Then select `Move and size with cells` in the `Properties` tab. This will make sure that each checkbox hides with the column and gets copied over with the column.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks! the last two hours searching how to hide it worth it right now.

Comment: Fernando - sorry, this doesn't solve the copying issue, but it does solve the hiding issue. Actually, can you be more clear in what you want. I thought I understood but I am not sure. This is what I think: 1) Find new Column 2) Copy column and checkbox (or make new checkbox)? 3) hide newly created column and checkbox?

Comment: actually is the option 2, i have the base column with the checkbox, (the D column in my code), and i want to copy that column with the checbox to the other columns, but the column D must be hide(all the data including the checkbox). I hope i'll be a more clear now, i'll edit the answer too to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman i see something peculiar, when the "Design Mode" is activated the cell with the checbox is copy with it to any other cells, but i can't use the button that i created to copy the colums because the Design Mode is activated. there should be a way to create a macro to activated before copy the column and deactivated when the data is copied?

Comment: Yes. Design Mode has different settings. However, see my answer below. Since the user wont ever be in design mode, the code I posted was tested and works, but read the comments to adjust to your specific worksheet setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this is a shot. There's probably a bit more of ideal way to do it, but I tested it and got it to work.

There are some assumptions on cell ranges and such that you will need to adjust to meet your exact spreadsheet specs.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdAddNewXref_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("mySheet") 'change as needed

    'find next column to copy
    i = 3
    Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop While ws.Cells(2, i) <> ""

    With ws.Columns("D:D")
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        .Copy Columns(i)
    End With

    'copy checkbox in column D
    Dim cb As Shape
    Set cb = ws.Shapes("CheckBox1") 'change name as needed
    cb.Copy
    ws.Cells(4, i).Select 'assumes checkbox should be in row 4, change to wherever it is on column D for you
    ws.Paste

    ws.Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

CHange the paste, to paste special values, to hide the check its the .visible property I believe.

hope this helps.

From what I gathered...  Copying the row, to somewhere else, but not the control, then he wanted to hide copied row. :)

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub test()


    '   From above code in yours I will be col number

    Dim i As Integer

i = 5

Columns("A:A").Copy

Sheet2.Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: just curious, did you actually test this answer before posting?

Comment: Hi,  yes I did.    f

Comment: Apologies, I read it as he didn't want it copied, ignore  me i'll delete my answer.  Long week! Cheers.

Comment: No, I realize now it's very unclear :) I just re-read it again and realized there are some ambiguities.

Comment: Between the two of us, he's learnt how to do it, which is the main thing :)

Comment: I edit my question, and i'll hope will be more clear, sorry for the ambiguities.